# How to get the selected value from a radio button group in React where there are multiple groups?

Tags: reactjs

I have a group of radio buttons like this :

```
return committees.map((committee) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <input type="radio" name={committee.shortName}
        ref={`${committee.shortName}Preference`} defaultChecked="true" value="1" />
      <label>1</label>
      <input type="radio" name={committee.shortName}
        ref={`${committee.shortName}Preference`} defaultChecked="true" value="2" />
      <label>1</label>
      <input type="radio" name={committee.shortName}
        ref={`${committee.shortName}Preference`} defaultChecked="true" value="3" />
      <label>1</label>
      <input type="radio" name={committee.shortName}
        ref={`${committee.shortName}Preference`} defaultChecked="true" value="4" />
      <label>1</label>
      <input type="radio" name={committee.shortName}
        ref={`${committee.shortName}Preference`} defaultChecked="true" value="5" />
      <label>1</label>
    </div>
  );
});
```

There are multiple groups like this in this page. React `ref` does not give me the right value. It gives the value as 5 (The last value) for all the groups. If I use `getElementsByName` it give me 5 elements (5 radio button fields). I need to get the selected value of the group. How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could keep an inner state with a map between commitee.shortName => selectedValue (updating the state onChange), and then add a:

```
checked={this.state.selectedValues[committee.shortName] === radioValue}
```

Here is a fiddle: [Radio Buttons Example](https://jsfiddle.net/omerts/dh9c1sbc/)

There is also a library that sugars it off for you:
[react-radio-group](https://github.com/chenglou/react-radio-group)

Comment: Great thanks! I used the react-radio-group plugin and it works. But one small thing, you have directly assigned a value to the state `this.state.selectedValues[committee.shortName] === radioValue`. We should use `setState` instead right?

Comment: Good to hear! This is not an assignment but rather a comparison. You could look at the fiddle, to see how it works.

Comment: Oh really sorry. My mistake! Thanks :-)

Comment: Great solution! Thanks for the fiddle!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using React I don't think it's a correct way to use it jQuery-style, using `ref` - React works nice as a final-state-machine and you should store your components data in `state` and do not request it accessing component by `ref`.

So you should add something like `onChange= ()=>this.setState({selectedValue: 'yourValue'})` to pass correctly changed value to the state, and if you want to use "controlled" input `value={this.state.selectedValue}` or in the case with radio buttons `checked={this.state.selectedValue === 'yourValue'}`.

But you do not really need use radio checks and groups with react, you could do something like this:

```
committies.map(committie => (
  <button className={this.state.selectedValue === committie.id ? 'selected' : ''}
          onClick={() => this.setState({selectedValue: committie.id})}>
      {committee.shortName}
  </button>
))
```